# Condensed notation for specifying an interval for several variables

Tags: notation

What is the most correct notation to specify an interval for several variables at the same time? E.g. if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in the interval $(0,\pi/4)$;

$$0<\alpha,\beta<\pi/4$$

$$0<\{\alpha,\beta\}<\pi/4$$

And perhaps even a third and better alternative?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your proposal, I prefer the first one, I think most people would understand it.

You can use $(\alpha,\beta)\in(0,\frac{\pi}4)^2$

Generally for an n-uplet $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ or $I^n$ for some interval $I$.

Since $I^n$ is a notation for set product $I\times I\cdots\times I$, you can also specify different intervals for different variables.

$\, z=re^{i\theta}$ with $(r,\theta)\in[0,3)\times[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2]$

$x\in\mathbb Q\iff x=\frac pq$ with $(p,q)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb N^*$